I am trying to push my code to heroku but repeatedly getting the error that it failed to push some refs with no other error message
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to college-compass.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/college-compass.git
[remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/college-compass.git'

First I was getting errors with gunicorn but it is in my requirements.txt and my procfile is correctly set up using web: gunicorn app:app.
Additionally when I try to run heroku run bash, it can't see any of the packages I have downloaded, even python and says command not found.
My build logs look fine, and my code has the proper structure including a Procfile, requirements.txt, runtime.txt which uses python 3.11.10, and my flask app is defined in app.py.
I think that my paths for heroku and my code might be different but I'm not sure how to resolve that.
I tried running it locally in my terminal and it works but for some reason it continuously fails on heroku.
I tried pushing on my virtual environment and off.
I used heroku python buildpack combined with the community apt one. I tried clearing the cache and force pushing.
I turned maintenance mode off for heroku. None of it is working.
These are my logs
2024-10-14T01:00:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: 
Build started by 
user arushishah2711@gmail.com

2024-10-14T01:03:50.457347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: 
State changed from crashed to starting

2024-10-14T01:03:53.190899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: 
Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`

2024-10-14T01:03:53.735153+00:00 app[web.1]: 
/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

2024-10-14T01:03:53.784052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: 
Process exited with status 127

2024-10-14T01:03:53.809774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: 
State changed from starting to crashed

2024-10-14T01:04:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- 
check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/99d1b65f-07e2-4dfa-a964-781a10a1efb6/activity/builds/2b99e226-0ce8-49af-a94a-905ba1568b65

2024-10-14T01:17:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: 
Build started by user arushishah2711@gmail.com

2024-10-14T01:21:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: 
Build failed -- check your build output:
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/99d1b65f-07e2-4dfa-a964-781a10a1efb6/activity/builds/e4bd7d7a-ae18-4085-a649-be4219b61018


This is your error message: "gunicorn: command not found". You need to install gunicorn.

The question is not related to git

Your build (CI) is not working due to the following error:
>>> gunicorn: command not found

---

2024-10-14T01:03:53.735153+00:00 app[web.1]: 
/bin/bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found



You don't have gunicorn installed
How to fix it:

$ pip install gunicorn
Add gunicorn to your requirements.txt

Follow the instruction how to integrate gunicorn with heroku.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#adding-gunicorn-to-your-application



gunicorn is installed in my environment and in my requirements.txt
